# Loop to process each line of text file in to one of three arrays

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I am trying to create a loop to split lines of a text file into different vectors where "persons" contains all lines, "v1" contains names, "v2" contains ages & "v3" contains pets. I have been able to push all lines to "persons" but how would I iterate over persons so that persons[0] = name, persons[1] = age, persons[2] = pet, persons[4] = name etc....? The code I have written gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
#include <io>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream people("myfile.txt");
    vector<string> persons;
    vector<string> first_names;
    vector<float> ages;
    vector<string> pets;
    string l;
    float age;

    if(!people)
    {
        printf("fail");
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(getline(people, l))
        {
            if (l.size() > 0)
            {
                people.push_back(l)
            }
        }
        int num = people.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i + 3)
        {
            first_names.push_back(people[i]);     // These are the
            ages.push_back(stof(people[i+1]));    // lines created to
            pets.push_back(people[i+2]);          // push to seperate
        }                                         // arrays.
        return 0
    }
}
```

Text file example

```
Bob
25.5
Snake
Kerry
29.5
Dog
```

Comment: The 2nd loop is infinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < num; i + 3)
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i += 3)
```

otherwise `i` will always be 0 and never more than `num-1`.

Comment: I think you got a down vote because errors caused by typos are not worth answering.

Comment: actually as a beginner c++ coder I haven't had to use += and didn't know to use it. I found the answer quite helpful

Comment: @w You might find compiler warnings much more helpful.

Comment: @273K, ok, fair enough. I guess it could have been a comment. To be fair, though, there is nothing in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer that says not to answer a question that has errors due to typo. Except, maybe suggesting that only 'good' questions be answered (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then again, SO awards a badge for getting upvotes on answers to downvoted questions, so I would say that the guidelines are not particularly clear on this point. I was just trying to help the OP out, and getting Mjoelnir'd for that is pretty annoying.